# How to limit the nearby location search according to the current location using google maps in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am making an android app in which whenever a user selects the clinic option inside the navigation drawer, he/she will be redirected to the in app map (that uses the google maps api key) which will show his/her current location and all the nearby clinics/hospitals with a list at the bottom of the map.

I have tried to implement that but not succeeded. I know there are many questions like this on SO but none of them fulfill my needs.

This is my **ClinicFragment** java file in which I want to display the map with all the services and a list of nearby hospitals.

```
public class ClinicFragment extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

public static final String TAG = ClinicFragment.class.getSimpleName();

/*
 * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
 * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
 */
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;



private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clinic_fragment);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    new GetPlaces(this, getListView()).execute();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}




class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private String[] placeName;
    private String[] imageUrl;
    private ListView listView;

    public GetPlaces(Context context, ListView listView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,placeName));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        dialog.isIndeterminate();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PlacesServices service = new PlacesServices("paste your place api key");
        List<Place> findPlaces = service.findPlaces(28.632808,77.218276,"hospital");  // hospiral for hospital
        // atm for ATM

        placeName = new String[findPlaces.size()];
        imageUrl = new String[findPlaces.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < findPlaces.size(); i++) {

            Place placeDetail = findPlaces.get(i);
            placeDetail.getIcon();

            System.out.println(  placeDetail.getName());
            placeName[i] =placeDetail.getName();

            imageUrl[i] =placeDetail.getIcon();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Place.java**

```
public class Place {
private String id;
private String icon;
private String name;
private String vicinity;
private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
}

static Place jsonToPontoReferencia(JSONObject pontoReferencia) {
    try {
        Place result = new Place();
        JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) pontoReferencia.get("geometry");
        JSONObject location = (JSONObject) geometry.get("location");
        result.setLatitude((Double) location.get("lat"));
        result.setLongitude((Double) location.get("lng"));
        result.setIcon(pontoReferencia.getString("icon"));
        result.setName(pontoReferencia.getString("name"));
        result.setVicinity(pontoReferencia.getString("vicinity"));
        result.setId(pontoReferencia.getString("id"));
        return result;
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Place.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Place{" + "id=" + id + ", icon=" + icon + ", name=" + name + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + '}';
}
```

**PlacesServices.java**

```
public class PlacesServices {

private String API_KEY;

public PlacesServices(String apikey) {
    this.API_KEY = apikey;
}

public void setApiKey(String apikey) {
    this.API_KEY = apikey;
}

public List<Place> findPlaces(double latitude, double longitude,String placeSpacification)
{

    String urlString = makeUrl(latitude, longitude,placeSpacification);


    try {
        String json = getJSON(urlString);

        System.out.println(json);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");


        ArrayList<Place> arrayList = new ArrayList<Place>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            try {
                Place place = Place.jsonToPontoReferencia((JSONObject) array.get(i));

                Log.v("Places Services ", "" + place);


                arrayList.add(place);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PlacesServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
//https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=apikey
private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

    if (place.equals("")) {
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&radius=1000");
        //   urlString.append("&types="+place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    } else {
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&radius=1000");
        urlString.append("&types="+place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    }


    return urlString.toString();
}

protected String getJSON(String url) {
    return getUrlContents(url);
}

private String getUrlContents(String theUrl)
{
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return content.toString();
}
```

I am able to get the current location but limiting the nearby search to hospital and getting the list of those nearby hospitals with their details is not happening.

Please can anyone help me out with this.

Thank you

Comment: you need to specify `types` and `bounds` here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: @KayAnn Have you tried this? I am asking this because if you tried this then [please can you provide me some tutorial link. So that it will be easy for me to understand as I have already wasted a lot of time in this

Comment: There you go: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Comment: @KayAnn I have tried this code and its not working. Thanks

Comment: @KayAnn locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this); always shows null pointer exception

Comment: Where's the location listener? or what is `this` here?

Comment: its from the link you have provided @KayAnn

Comment: I think this is a better tutorial for you: http://www.taywils.me/2013/05/06/androidgoogleplacestutorial.html. But note that in this one he is requesting XML resource and thus implementing XML parsing you can do either. And also that these tutorials are references only, you would have to make adjustments in the code to make it work.

Comment: Basically how the implementation should be is you would still need to have a locationManager and LocationListener interface to get locationUpdates to know where the client device is at any given time so that you can take those co-ordinates and do this radius and type search request these places by doing a GET request and parse the response from Google Places API and show it inside your maps UI. Hope this clarifies it!